# Which kind of Overlord is Momonga?

Tags: overlord

On the [Wiki](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Overlord) I've found that there exist three types of overlords:

> **Types of Overlord**
>
> - **Overlord Wiseman:** They're skilled in magic.
> - **Overlord Cronos Master:** They could use time-related special abilities.
> - **Overlord General:** They're adept at controlling armies of the undead.

**Which type of overlord is Momonga (Ainz Ooal Gown)?** It seems that he has a bit of each one ability...

- **He is extremely powerful using magic.** (Actually, I haven't seen any other lvl 100 mage so I can't say if he is "stronger" than other mages...).
- **He can stop time.** (In the Overlord 3<sup>rd</sup> season chapter 13 of Anime he frozen time for a few seconds).
- **He can create undead creatures.** (He has made Death Knights from corpses and he is able to give them orders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer your question, I'll briefly elaborate on the overlord species. Overlord is the highest race of undead who primarily have the appearance of skeletons.  Just like other undead species, the overlord class  is the final form of both the skeleton mage and Elder Lich class (most undead would have to gain enough levels to evolve through up to that point). However even within the overlord race, there are different levels.

According to the wiki: "Momonga has an Overlord racial level of five." Even though we aren't told exactly how many levels are within the overlord class. It makes sense to say that the higher the level within the overlord race, the more powerful the individual overlord. I'm guessing this makes Ainz Oal Gown pretty special when compared to the typical average overlord (more like the 5 overlords that guard the nazarick grand  library, there is big difference between them and momonga in terms of power level and abilities). This could explain why he has characteristics of the 3 different types of overlords.

So to answer your question, Momonga is not an ordinary Overlord, his superiority in level among the overlord race probably gives him the advantage of being an overlord with abilities similar to all 3 types. ( He also has dark wisdom, allowing him to learn spells that he probably couldn't. This cheat ability makes him nearly invisible because we don't know for sure which specific spells he learnt from the dark wisdom ability) I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Interesting answer, maybe is he "superior" due to its very specialized build into necromancy?. By the way, it seems to me or you have said that Overlord race has more than 5 levels? Maybe, I've misunderstood. I'll wait a day or two before accepting your answer, maybe another user wants to answer in that time.

Comment: NAh what i meant is there are levels within the overlord race(because if momonga is level 5 then it makes sense to hypothetically say that). Neither the anime nor the wiki expressly states exactly how many levels are within the race. But i'd guess that since Ainz is max level he is probably pretty close to highest level of overlord if not the highest

Comment: From what I remember reading the overlord class does not unlock until 95 levels in other things which would imply that level 5 is the highest they can get.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin We learn that Overlord is a Rare class, and that all rare classes max out at a total of 5 levels.

Answer (score 0):

The “Overlord Wiseman” and “Overlord Cronos Master” are “stock characters” that are repeatedly created by various effects in the Yggdrasil game, much like there was also data for a generic “Goblin Archer” and “Goblin Wolf-Rider” that each got used MULTIPLE times when Enri Ermot used the first Horn (and then differentiated into different PEOPLE). PCs and custom NPCs don’t necessarily match generic stock characters that the game has on hand for summoning spells, and random encounters.